# 74th derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this HW where I have to calculate the $74$th derivative of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)\arctan(x)$ at $x=0$.
I have no Idea where to begin with.
Someone in previous post suggested using Taylor, but I can't because we haven't learned it yet

Comment: I suggested the OP repost his new question, or add at the bottom of the earlier post. The OP's first non-duplicate post was asking for confirmation (or challenge) to the "non-existence" of the second derivative, and hence all higher order derivatives. Now s/he is asking for help with how to approach answering the question regarding the 74th derivative of his/her function evaluated at $0$.